# What does the value of the bits variable means?

Tags: bash, awk, syntax

I'm trying to get the prefix from a subnet mask, the code is the following:

```
mask=255.255.254.0

oct1=$(echo $mask | awk -F. '{print $1}')
oct2=$(echo $mask | awk -F. '{print $2}')
oct3=$(echo $mask | awk -F. '{print $3}')
oct4=$(echo $mask | awk -F. '{print $4}')

for i in {1..4}; do
  for j in {7..0}; do
    bits=$((oct$i & ((1 << $j)) ? 1 : 0))
    ((prefix += $bits))
  done
done
echo $prefix
```

This actually works, but I don't know what the value of the variable bits means or does.

Comment: `IFS=. read oct1 oct2 oct3 oct4 <<< "$mask"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bits variable is tallying up the number of bits in each octet of your mask...it expresses the subnet mask in a bit count that could be used in CIDR notation.

Example 192.168.1.1 with subnet 255.255.254.0 in CIDR notation is 192.168.1.1/23.  Each octet of the subnet mask is a full byte (or 8 bits).  255 = all 8 bits turned on.  So 255.255.254.0 is 255 (8bits) + 255 (8bits) + 254 (7bits) + 0 (0bits) = 23 bits turned on.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that but what the "&" and "? 1 : 0" do? Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: It's a ternary operator - basically an inline If statement:  
(eval expression) ? (true expression) : (false expression)

So: if the octet value's "j" bit evals to TRUE, return 1 otherwise return 0.

Comment: The & is a bitwise AND comparison operator.